# IIS Multiple process Issue

Tags: sql, iis

IIS creates another worker process (w3wp.exe) for an application pool. When there are two worker processes working at the same time and you try and load the the web application, it will just hang and not load at all. On a rare occasion, the server clears down one of the IIS worker process,  it then regains normal working order and you can load the website again. However, 8 times out of 10, they need to reboot their server in order to clear the process and gain working use of the website.
 Has anyone seen something like this before or have any ideas as to what this could be and how we can get round it? We are using Windows Authentication for the website.

Comment: for one application pool,there will be one worker process,when you think it hangs ,try to get a dump using debug diag,search for tess fernandez msdn, you will find a lot of good info

Comment: also i recommend closing this question here and asking it in https://superuser.com/

Comment: since Stackoverflow is mostly related to programming